# Hopscotch close modal onNext or onEnd

Tags: javascript, html, hopscotch

I'm confused. I can open the modal using this:

```
onNext: function() {
   $('#modal').modal('toggle');
}
```

But I can't close the modal with the same function with another `$('#modal').modal('toggle');` or `$('#modal').modal('hide')`.

I even tried creating a registerHelper but it still doesn't.

```
hopscotch.registerHelper('closeModal', function() {
      $('#modal').modal('toggle');
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I made a mistake. I can close the modal using the `onEnd` setting.

```
var tour = {
  id: 'tour1',
  steps: [{
            target: 'Target',
            title: 'Target Title',
            content: 'Target Content'
         }
         ],
         onEnd: ["closeModal"]
}
```

Made a callback helper to close the modals.

```
hopscotch.registerHelper('closeModal', function() {
      $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```